# Невозможно соединиться с удаленным сервером

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь загрузить файл на сервер, при этом возникает исключение System.Net.WebException: "Невозможно соединиться с удаленным сервером". В чём может быть проблема? Пароль FTP верный, логин тоже, файл присутствует.

```
UploadFileToServer("fs_chat.txt", "fsoc.ucoz.net/fs_chat.txt");

private void UploadFileToServer(string from, string to) 
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        Uri ftp = new Uri("ftp://login:password@" + to);
        client.UploadFile(ftp.ToString(), from);
    }
}
```

Comment: А если использовать `NetworkCredential` для авторизации? (скажем, как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35953651/6808809))

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не знаю, как этим пользоваться, моё обучение не дошло до этой вещицы :)

Comment: Я вам дал ссылку, где написан простейший код с авторизацией и отправкой на `FTP`.

Answer (score 1):

(WebClient) но эта простой API. 
даешь имя пользователя и пароль в объект 'NetworkCredentials' и передаешь этот объект в (WebClient) свойства -> Credentials.
передаешь адрес , метод и путь файла в UploadFile().

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
   client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("имя пользователя", "пароль");
   client.UploadFile("ftp://ftpserver.com/target.zip", "STOR", "локальный путь 
   к файлу");
}
```